# What are all the known questions that have been asked as part of a Voigt-Kampff test?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

For the past few weeks, I have been looking for a list of all the known the questions (or statements) to have been asked as part of a Voigt-Kampff test  (or Voight-Kampff as they say in the first movie).

To my surprise, there is no such thing online, or I'm not searching properly. I can just stumble on a few fan made questionnaire online there and there, which usually don't have all the questions.

What are the known questions to be asked by competent Blade Runners?

I am interested by all the relevant sources (a few example of which I am aware of: *Blade Runner (1982)* and the game *Blade Runner (1997)*, maybe *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* too if it's relevant).

Comment: OK. I've been through both films (and every version of their scripts that I can find), all the [comics](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Comic_books), the [original story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F), all four video games, all the [sequel books](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Runner_2:_The_Edge_of_Human), all the short films and all the novelisations. I think I'm pretty much done here until the new TV series comes out. Since it's set in 2032, it shouldn't contain any VK test material, but I'm guessing they'll fit some in somehow.

Comment: If anyone lives in New York and wants to check out the script for the [play adaptation of Do Android Dream](https://www.worldcat.org/title/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep-typescript-2010/oclc/893574854), I think a small bounty would be in order for them.

Comment: And lo and behold, they managed to fit a VK test into the new animated TV series, despite it making zero sense. Also the untrained guy who ran it only asked four questions, then pronounced the subject 'not a replicant', despite that it should have taken him hundreds of questions.

Comment: Two I remember: 1. What is your favorite color? 2. What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow? It is strange how revealing these questions are -- had he asked Rachael them first, he would have known immediately.

Comment: @releseabe Hmm, I don't remember these questions. Did he ask her these in the movie?

Comment: @releseabe Ah, it's a Monty Python reference.

Comment: Only the answers are important. How many things does it have to say until you realize you're talking to GPT?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***[Blade Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner)*** (1982) ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWPyRSURYFQ), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Umc9ezAyJv0))

- It’s your birthday. Someone gives you a calfskin wallet.
- You’ve got a little boy. He shows you his butterfly collection plus
  the killing jar.
- You’re watching television. Suddenly you realize there’s a wasp
  crawling on your arm.
- You’re in a desert walking along in the sand when all of the sudden
  you look down, and you see a tortoise, it’s crawling toward you. You
  reach down, you flip the tortoise over on its back. The tortoise lays
  on its back, its belly baking in the hot sun, beating its legs trying
  to turn itself over, but it can’t, not without your help. But you’re
  not helping. Why is that?
- Describe in single words, only the good things that come into your mind about your mother.
- You're reading a magazine. You come across a full-page nude photo of
  a girl. You show it to your husband. He likes it so much, he hangs it
  on your bedroom wall.
- You become pregnant by a man who runs off with your best friend, and
  you decide to get an abortion.
- You're watching a stage play - a banquet is in progress. The guests
  are enjoying an appetizer of raw oysters. The entree consists of
  boiled dog.

---

An [**early draft script**](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Blade-runner_early.html) for the film includes some additional wording for the final question:

- You're watching an old movie.  It shows a banquet in progress, the guests are enjoying raw oysters. The entree consists of boiled dog stuffed with rice. The raw oysters are less acceptable to you than a dish of boiled dog.

---

The [**official novelisation of Blade Runner**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner) contains similar wording

> "You're watching an old movie. It shows people enjoying a meal of raw oysters. ... The next course is boiled dog stuffed with rice. ... Raw oysters are less acceptable to you than a dish of boiled dog"
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner: A Story of the Future](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner)</sup></sub>

---

***[Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F)*** (1968)

- You are given a calf-skin wallet on your birthday...
- You have a little boy and he shows you his butterfly collection, including his killing jar.
- You’re sitting watching TV, and suddenly you discover a wasp crawling on your wrist.
- In a magazine you come across a full-page color picture of a nude girl. Your husband likes the picture. The girl is lying facedown on a large and beautiful bearskin rug. Your husband hangs the picture up on the wall of his study.
- You’re reading a novel written in the old days before the war. The characters are visiting Fisherman’s Wharf in San Francisco. They become hungry and enter a seafood restaurant. One of them orders lobster, and the chef drops the lobster into the tub of boiling water while the characters watch.
- You rent a mountain cabin, in an area still verdant. It’s rustic knotty pine with a huge fireplace. On the walls someone has hung old maps, Currier and Ives prints, and above the fireplace a deer’s head has been mounted, a full stag with developed horns. The people with you admire the decor of the cabin and you all decide—
- You become pregnant, by a man who has promised to marry you. The man goes off with another woman, your best friend; you get an abortion and—
- You’re dating a man and he asks you to visit his apartment. While you’re there he offers you a drink. As you stand holding your glass you see into the bedroom; it’s attractively decorated with bullfight posters, and you wander in to look closer. He follows after you, closing the door. Putting his arm around you, he says—
- You are watching an old movie on TV, a movie from before the war. It shows a banquet in progress; the guests are enjoying raw oysters. The entrée consists of boiled dog, stuffed with rice. Are raw oysters more acceptable to you than a dish of boiled dog?
- My briefcase. Nice, isn’t it? Department issue. Babyhide. One hundred percent genuine human babyhide. (note that this doesn't appear to be one of the *formal* questions)

---

The ***[BBC Radio Play of Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F_(radio))*** (2014)  contains the same questions, albeit phrased slightly differently ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhNSR0WaYzc))

- You're given a calfskin wallet on your birthday.
- You are the mother of a little boy. He shows you his butterfly collection, including the killing jar.
- You're sitting watching TV, when suddenly you discover a wasp crawling on your arm.
- In a magazine you come across a photo of a naked woman in a provocative pose. Your husband likes the picture. The girl is lying face-down on a beautiful bearskin rug. Your husband hangs the picture on the wall in his den.
- You're reading a novel written in the old days before the war. The characters visit a fish restaurant. One of them orders a lobster and the chef drops it alive into a tub of boiling water right in front of you.
- You become pregnant by a man who has promised to marry you. The man goes off with your best friend. You get an abortion.

---

***[Blade Runner: Black Lotus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9359796/)*** (2021) ([1](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=864438927575811))

- Picture your mother, and the house you grew up in. She looks at you, disappointed, and tells you that she doesn't love you, she's never loved you, and she regrets ever having you.
- You're passing a busy street corner on the way to a friend's apartment and you see a small cardboard box next to a dumpster. Inside is a tabby-cat, a kitten. A real one, with green eyes and a white spot on her nose, yowling for food.
- Why do you like cats?
- Can you remember being in love? How did it make you feel? How old were you?

---

[***Blade Runner: The Video Game***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_(1997_video_game)) (1997) ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__Y6ktslSYw))

***Low intensity questions:***

- Are you taking any drugs?
- A man dressed in rags approaches you on the street and asks you for money. Do you buy him dinner or take him to a shelter?
- You're crying. Why is that?
- When did you stop beating your spouse?
- Using the first words that come into your mind, describe your childhood.
- You're suddenly very afraid. Why?
- You noticed someone attractive across the room.
- You return from work to find that your home has been burglarized.
- For your anniversary, your spouse gives you a real goldfish.
- You're having a very erotic dream.
- Describe in single words, only the good things that come into your mind about, your mother.
- How old are you?
- Out of the corner of your eye, you see a large black spider crawling up the wall.
- It's the first day of school and the teacher calls on you.
- Your best friend has done something to make you angry.

***Medium intensity***

- You have a little boy. He shows you his butterfly collection plus the
  killing jar.
- Your child comes home with a black eye.
- You've been drafted into the army. During a boot-camp hazing, you're
  bound, blindfolded and force to eat worms.
- A teacher calls you stupid in front of the rest of the class.
- You pour yourself a drink. Every time you finish one, you have another
  until you vomit. You wake up hungover and depressed.
- You're seven years old. You've managed to steal several marshmallows from the kitchen and sneak them back to your bedroom. You're caught and your father spanks you.
- You suddenly feel the urge to commit suicide.
- What's the most embarrassing thing that ever happened to you?
- You're giving a speech to a crowd of hundreds. First, one person starts to laugh. He leans over and says something to the people around him. Soon,
  the whole audience is roaring with laughter and pointing at you.
- You see a documentary about 20th century tuna boats. At the end, you feel like taking up fishing.
- You're having dinner at a friend's home. Halfway through the appetizer, he tells you that you've been eating goose liver pâté.
- In a magazine, you come across a full page photo of a nude girl. The girl is lying on a bear skin rug.
- You're visiting the dentist. At the receptionist's desk is a huge bowl of fresh cut flowers.
- You're given a calf-skin wallet for your birthday.
- You're watching TV. Suddenly you noticed a wasp crawling on your wrist.

***High Intensity***

- You're in a desert, walking along in the sand, when all of a sudden you
  look down and see a tortoise. It's crawling towards you. You reach down and flip the tortoise on its back. The tortoise lays on its back, its belly is baking in the hot sun. Beating its legs, trying to turn himself over. But it can't, not without your help. But you're not helping. Why is that?
- You're watching an old movie. It shows a banquet in progress. The guests
  are enjoying raw oysters. The entrée consists of boiled dog.
- You see an oversized book with pictures of exotic animals on the cover. The title is "Big-Game Hunting in Zaire" Curious, you flip it open. There's a picture of a man standing with his  foot on a dead Cape buffalo. You find yourself fascinated. You keep paging through it, seeing picture after picture of animals laid to waste. Each more gruesome than the last.
- You've been kidnapped. Your captors tell you that you'd better think about what you did to deserved this.
- You're at a restaurant with friends. One of them orders lobster. The chef drops the lobster into the tub of boiling water, while you watch.
- You rent a mountain cabin. On a wall, someone has hung old maps and Currier & Ives prints. A deer's head is mounted above the fireplace. A full stag with developed horns.
- Like my briefcase? Department issue, baby hide. 100% genuine human baby hide.
- You're going to die. It maybe soon. Death, the grave, rot.
- You're on a farm. You get into the pen to feed the pigs. In their excitement, the animals knock you down into the mud. Using a butcher knife, you slit the throat of the nearest sow. You're covered in blood as you stumble to your feet.
- What do you think it's like, to be a Replicant?

---

***[Blade Runner: Revelations](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Runner:_Revelations)*** (2018) ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg-Om5QT9o0))

- A friend owes you money and claims to be broke. You notice this same friend wearing an expensive watch the next day. How do you handle the situation?
- Imagine that you're lost in a dark forest. You come upon a frightened young girl. A pack of wild wolved has surrounded her but then you realize, she's a replicant. Would you save [her]?
- A co-worker lies to get a promotion you wanted. If you report it, they will most likely be fired and you'll receive the promotion. Do you turn them in?

---

***[Blade Runner 2019](https://www.goodreads.com/series/301020-blade-runner-2019)***

- You're alone in a barn. There is no hay on the floor. A ewe is giving birth. Something's wrong. The lamb is trapped in the birth canal. The ewe is screaming. Blood and placenta pool on the floor. What do you choose to do? ([#1](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45214029-blade-runner-2019-1))
- You're in a cathedral. The eucharist is underway. When it's your turn, you see that the wafer is a small clump of human hair. ([#6](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48691929-blade-runner-2019-6))
- You're in a park. You see a young girl, flying a kite, alone. The girl begins to wrap the line tightly around her neck. Her skin bleeds. ([#6](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48691929-blade-runner-2019-6))

---

The on-screen prop (on Holden's desk) was put [up for auction](https://propstoreauction.com/lot-details/index/catalog/359/lot/119555?url=%2Fsearch%3Fpage%3D37%26key%3D%26view%3Dlist) in November 2023 by the [Museum of Pop Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_Pop_Culture) in Seattle.

> This Voight-Kampff test comprises 18 pages of mathematical, linguistic and behavioural multiple-choice questions, contained in a silver-coloured card cover labelled "Voight Kampff".

The test appears to consist of various maths and word puzzles, tests of scientific knowledge and [visuospatial acuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visuospatial_function) before you get to the nitty gritty questions designed to evoke an emotional response.

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. This page contains 2 questions. Each one shows a structural formula of some kind of chemical compound, with 4 possible answers. The idea is to determine what is the correct molecular formula for the given chemical compound.]

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. This page shows a mathematical structure called "graph" from "Graph Theory"; not to be confused with a statistical graph for example. The 3 questions have 4 possible answers, and involve understanding the graph drawing, such as the maximum flow from the starting point to the end, and the maximum capacity for a specific section of the graph.]

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. This one contains 5 questions. The objective is to find out the wrong answer or answers among the choices. These questions involve knowledge in physics.]

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. This page contains 4 questions. Each question gives the beginning of a definition. The last word is missing, and 1 of the 4 available answers to each question is the correct choice to complete the given definition.]

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. This one shows 18 different kind of shapes, with different rotations and filled with different kind of patterns. The exercise here is to pair them up to form an ellipse, an hexagon, a rectangle, a triangle or a trapezoid. There is 5 questions and each one of them have 5 possible answers.]

[image: A picture of one of the pages of the prop. Each lines contain either a word or a sentence, followed by 4 boxes lined on the right. Possibly a written version of the Voight-Kampff test.]

[image: This picture shows the cover of the Voight-Kampff prop book. The page is white and is adorned with a black bordered rectangle filled with white. In the lower right corner, Voight-Kampff is written. The paper seems to be worn out.]

Comment: What's a tortoise?

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt - Delicious in soup

Comment: I remember the Wasp question from the movie.

Comment: Is this answer testing whether I’m a replicant or a lesbian?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Just answer the question, please. Edit: I just realised the joke doesn't work with "answer" instead of "question". Maybe: "Just question the answer, please."

Comment: Now I wish they actually showed all 18 pages. But damn, I'm really curious as to how they intended to prove someone was a replicant with these "exercises".

Comment: @Clockwork - I've asked the auction house for a look-see, but they've refused. You can buy the document direct from the seller though, if you want to actually own the prop from the film.

Comment: @Valorum Uh, tempting, but I don't think I'm curious enough about its content to sell my house x)

Comment: @Clockwork - It failed to meet its reserve at £3000 at an auction of scifi memorabilia. I'm assuming they'll accept £3K now.

Comment: I'm glad to see this answer's upvotes caught up to the question's. There was a time there was nearly 10 votes of difference (yeah, I pay attention to that kind of detail).

Answer (score 7):

This VK test is part of an original annotated script for Blade Runner and is on display at the [Museum of Pop Culture](https://www.mopop.org/) in Seattle, alongside numerous other original props and artifacts from the film.

[image: lines on the left with four check boxes on the right of each]

As plain text:

> - Tortoise
> - Insects
> - Calf Skin
> - Butterflies
> - Television Viewing
> - Nude Photo
> - Raw Oysters
> - Boiled Dog
> - Skinned Snake
> - I have seen visions.
> - I am often constipated.
> - Poetry excites me.
> - I like very sweet foods.
> - I would like to grow things.
> - As a child I wet my pants.
> - Alcohol is bad for you.
> - At times I try to do too much.
> - I deserve to be punished for my sins.
> - I never liked to go to dances.
> - I sometimes get angry over nothing.
> - I love my father more than my mother.
> - Spiders make me nervous.
> - I blush often.
> - I read the Bible often.
> - I am a very relaxed person.
> - Someone is out to get me.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a web page that would corroborate what you've said in this answer?

Comment: You mean like this one? https://www.flickr.com/photos/jpellgen/51451506427/in/photostream/

Comment: Can confirm this matches the photo I took of this same artifact back in September. I'd thought of this question at the time and then forgot all about it

Comment: The display is labeled "Interrogation Manual for the Voight-Kampff machine used in the film Blade Runner, 1982". Happy to edit in my photo of the placard next to it if you'd like.

Comment: @KernelPanic Feel free to add in your own photo if it's relevant. That would actually help I think in showing that it's a relevant picture.

Comment: I've given this answer a bonus. Kudos for finding the actual question sheet used by Holden :-)

Comment: It might interest you that I've found the actual prop auction. It had quite a few more pictures; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/272583/20774